# Jtable data to txt

Tags: java, swing, file, netbeans, jtable

I am trying to export my jTable to text file. Here is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < table.getColumnCount(); y++) {

                if (table.getValueAt(i, y) != null) {

                        bw.write(table.getValueAt(i, y) + "   ");

                } 

            }

            bw.newLine();
        }
```

Everything works fine with all cells filled with values. But when I only fill half of the cells the export is not perfect. The last value is missing.
    for example:

```
    [value1][value2][value3]
    [value4][value5][value6]
    [value7][value8][value9]
```

prints all the values to text file.
but this:

```
    [value1][value2][value3]
    [value4][value5][value6]
    [null][null][null]
```

prints  only value1, value2, value3, value4 and value5.
Where is the problem?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*unable to fetch current value of cell being edited*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20910983/230513).

Comment: Trashgod- thank you very much. It works. You can write your answer as answer so I can give you credit for Solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public void writeTXT(JTable table) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
  Writer writer = null;
  try{
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("filename.txt")));
    StringBuffer bufferHeader = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i<table.getColumnCount();i++){
      bufferHeader.append(table.getColumnName(i));
      if(i!=table.getColumnCount()) bufferHeader.append(" ");
    }
    writer.write(bufferHeader.toString()+"\r\n");

    for(int j = 0; j<table.getRowCount(); j++){
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
      for (int k = 0; k<table.getColumnCount(); k++){
        buffer.append(table.getValueAt(j,k));
        if(k!=table.getColumnCount()) buffer.append(" ");
      }
      writer.write(buffer.toString()+"\r\n");
    }
  }finally{
    writer.close();
  }
}
```

Don't include the first for-loop if you don't have column names/don't need them.